# Liouville's type theorem in PDEs theory

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations

I was reading some research articles concerning the Liouville's type theorem in PDEs (Almost all of them are entitled Liouville's type theorem for ...). Here is the statement of one of those theorem for the stationary magneto-hydrodynamics system (MHD)

> Let $(u, H)$ be a smooth solution of system (MHD) with $u,~ H \in BMO^{−1}(\mathbb{R}^3)$.
>   If we additionally require that $u,~ H \in L^q(\mathbb{R}^3)$ for $2<q<6$, then $u \equiv 0$ and $H \equiv 0$.

Can we confirm that this type of theorems **(The Liouville's type theorems)** are named after the well known Liouville theorem in complex analysis which reads

> Every holomorphic bounded function $f$, i.e.: there exists a positive number $M$ such that ${\displaystyle |f(z)|\leq M}$ for all ${\displaystyle z} \in {\displaystyle \mathbb {C} }$ is constant.

In other words, in PDEs theory we can call a Liouville's type theorem  every result that states:

> If a function $f$ belongs to a specific functional (class/spaces), then $f$ is either constant or identically zero.

Comment: 1. What does $BMO^{-1}$ represent in the expression $H \in BMO^{-1}$? 2. It will be hard to determine if  what you are asking is true without seeing the context in which it is written. Can you give us the titles of the research articles?

Comment: $BMO^{-1}$ is a functional space, $BMO$ itself stands for the bounded mean oscillation: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_mean_oscillation

Answer (score 1):

It is close. I would say that a Liouville-type theorem is one that says that all solutions of a given PDE in a certain function space are constant. For many function spaces, zero is of course the only constant function that belongs to them.

In the classical Liouville theorem you can take as PDE the Laplace equation for the real and imaginary part and as function space $L^\infty$. I would go so far to say that the classical model for these Liouville-type theorems is the result that states that every bounded harmonic function in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is constant. That these solutions happen to be real and imaginary parts of holomorphic functions on $\mathbb{C}$ is just a nice coincidence and a theorem that happens to have a name.